# Views Exposed filter text search for multiple value field

Tags: views

I have 6 fields (in Profile2) I want to combine into an exposed "`Global: Combine field filter`":

- Field 1 = text field with 1 value (text)
- Field 2 = text field with 1 value (text)
- Field 3 = text field with 1 value (text)
- Field 4 = text field with 1 value (text)
- Field 5 = long text field with 1 value (long text)
- Field 6 = text field set to **unlimited number of values** (text)

That last one is the problem. I want the user to be able to add several distinct values in this field, and I want to be able to create a combined field text search that includes the text from all of these fields, including all the separate values in Field 6.

If I *isolate* Field 6 and give it it's own exposed filter search field, it works fine. **But** if I try to make it one of the combined fields (using the `Global: Combine fields filter`), searches don't see the various text values in Field 6.

[BTW, I'm using **Better Exposed Filters**, though I don't think they are in use for the `Global: Combine fields filter`.]

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to add a (7th) Text field filtering on the same data as Field 6 and group it with an OR to Field 6. Then, you can use Field 7 in the `Global: Combine fields` filter and not have it overwrite the use-supplied values in Field 6.